# JQuery hide <p> does not seem to work?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Okay... obviously this is because I am so new. I don't understand why this does not work. I thought this is because the argument its not inside a function but I don't really know.

```
<head>
    <title>Documento sin título</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js">
        $(function(){
            $("p").hide();
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <p>hi</p>
</body>
```

Comment: You need have 2 `<script>` tags.  One with the `src` and one with your code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It should look like this:

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('p').hide();
    });
</script>
```

First you must load the external Javascript file (like `jquery.js`) in its own `script` tags. Then you include your Javascript (or jQuery for this case) in its own `script` tags.

Comment: You can also look [here](https://jsfiddle.net/mkurzweil/6snqcaex/). The solution is also given by @GrzegorzGajda

Answer (score 1):

Your code works!

However, you need to load the JS file first.  The function to hide the `p` should be in its own `<script>` tag (different one from loading the script)

```js
$(function() {

  $("p").hide();

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>hi</p>
<div>world!</div>
```